# Proof verification and questions about the Hamming Metric

Tags: proof-verification, metric-spaces

**Show that $(X,d_1)$ is a metric space**
Let $X$ be a non-empty set and $\mathbf{x},\mathbf{y},\mathbf{z}\in X$ vectors of length $n$, e.g. $\mathbf{x}=(x_1,x_2,...,x_n)$ such that $x_i\in\{0,1\}$. Then we define the *Hamming metric* as $d_1(\mathbf{x},\mathbf{y})=\sum_i^{n}|x_i-y_i|$, that is the number of indices $k$ sucht that $x_k\neq y_k$.

According to my lecture notes I need to show *(i) positivity*, *(ii) symmetry*, and *(iii) triangle inequality*. I think the first two properties are fairly easy to prove, though I'm not sure if I wrote it down correctly - so let's just do it:

*(i)* If $\mathbf{x}=\mathbf{y}$ then $d_1(\mathbf{x},\mathbf{y})=d_1(\mathbf{x},\mathbf{x})=\sum_i^{n}|x_i-x_i|=0$ and vice versa. Moreover the sum of an absolut function $|x_i-y_i|$ guarantees positivity for all arbitrary $\mathbf{x},\mathbf{y}$ so there's that.

*(ii)* For all $\mathbf{x},\mathbf{y}\in X$ follows that
\begin{align}
d_1(\mathbf{x},\mathbf{y})&=\sum_i^{n}|x_i-y_i|\\
&=\sum_i^{n}|-y_i+x_i|\\
&=\sum_i^{n}|-(y_i-x_i)|\\
&=\sum_i^{n}|y_i-x_i|\\
&=d_1(\mathbf{y},\mathbf{x}).
\end{align}

*(iii)* Now that's a bit more interesting. By using the triangle inequality for absolute values in $(\star)$ we get
\begin{align}
d_1(\mathbf{x},\mathbf{y})&=\sum_i^{n}|x_i-y_i|\\
&=\sum_i^{n}|x_i-z_i+z_i-y_i|\\
&\overset{(\star)}{\leq}\sum_i^{n}|x_i-z_i|+\sum_i^{n}|z_i-y_i|\\
&=d_1(\mathbf{x},\mathbf{z})+d_1(\mathbf{z},\mathbf{y})\\
\end{align}

as required. Perhaps I should add that $(\star)$ is given by applying the commonly known triangle inequality for absolute values multiple times. Isn't that just a proof by induction? Anyway, I simply noted that
\begin{align}
\sum_{i=1}^n |(x_i-z_i)+(z_i-y_i)|&=|(x_1-z_1)+(z_1-y_1)|+\dots+|(x_n-z_n)+(z_n-y_n)|\\
&\leq |x_1-z_1|+|z_1-y_1|+\dots+|x_n-z_n|+|z_n-y_n|\\
&=\sum_i^n\left(|x_i-z_i|+|z_i-y_i|\right)\\
&=\sum_{i=1}^n |x_i-z_i| + \sum_{i=1}^n |z_i-y_i|
\end{align}

---

**Show that $(X,d_2)$ is a metric space**

In **Problem 5** the hamming metric is defined this time by

$$d_2(\mathbf{x},\mathbf{y})=\text{the number of indices $k$ such that $x_k\neq y_k$}$$

where $\mathbf{x}=(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n)$ denotes messages consisting of $n$ symbols (letters, numbers, punctuation marks, space, etc.) while $X$ is the set of all messages of length $n$. Basically I have lost my previous binary pattern in favor of a more generalized metric; surely I can't just go ahead and compute the spins between two letters? I feel quite lost here since I don't see a definition I can work with yet. Maybe seeing some examples would clear up my confusion. For instance, in case we have $n=6$ what is $d_2(\mathbf{x},\mathbf{y})$ if $\mathbf{x}=(s,t,e,f,a,n)$ and $\mathbf{y}=(h,e,l,l,o,!)$?

Comment: Notice that although your vectors essentially have entries in $\{1,2,\dots,n\}$, the absolute value metric from the first section still serves the same purpose -- it tells you whether entries are identical or not. The only difference is that now these $|x_i-y_i|$ terms may have value larger than $1$. Nothing in your first proof used the fact that $x_i,y_i\in\{0,1\}$, so this shouldn't be a problem.